# AngularJS 1.5.0 redirect to controller on <tr> click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page that uses `ng-repeat` to populate a table. The table displays a list of companies. On table row click I want to open another page that has a form to edit the selected company.

This is the `html` page

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
        <td>{{company.companyName}}</td>
        <td>{{company.companyAddress}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the controller that should handle the click request

```
angular.module('companyApp.companyForm', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/updateCompany/:companyId', {
            templateUrl: 'app/companyForm/companyForm.html',
            controller: 'UpdatedCompanyController'
        });
    }])
    .controller('UpdatedCompanyController', ['$scope', '$resource',
        function ($scope, $resource) {

        }]);
```

I have tried using

```
$location.url("#/updateCompany").search({id:company.id})
```

But only a URL is created.

Also I tried using

```
window.location.href = //...
```

But again I'm redirected to default page when clicking on a table item.

How can I redirect to a new page on table row click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `$location.url("#/updateCompany").search({id:company.id})` will generate a `URL` like `#/updateCompany?id=1` & it would not match any of the .when condition provided in `$routeProvider`(will do nothing, as I looking at your config added in question).

This could solved by creating `URL` to match pattern of registered route in `$routeProvider`

```
$location.url("#/updateCompany/"+company.id)
```

Or you could use `$location.path` that will solve your issue

```
$location.path('/updateCompany/'+ company.id);
```

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-click="redirect(company)">
    <td>{{company.companyName}}</td>
    <td>{{company.companyAddress}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.redirect = function(company){
    $location.path('/updateCompany/'+ company.id);
};
```

Comment: So I should add ng-click="edit(company.id)" to <tr>?

Comment: @droid8421 in this case I'd say passing company object could be fine..`<tr ng-click="edit(company)"></tr>` should be fine

Comment: With $location.path('/updateCompany/'+ company.id); I'm redirected to default page. The issues is that URL already has #/companyList part and it tries to add the #/updateCompany also

Comment: @droid8421 `$location.path` will only replace the path after `#`, it should work.. I don't understand what you wanted to say..